# Passing references through a function?

Tags: c++, function, reference, ostringstream

I need to take some code within a function and put that within yet another function. The only problem is the variables are now out a scope. Whenever I try to pass them both as references I can hit with an onslaught of errors.

The relevant part of my code looks something like this:

```
Route::Route(std::string source) //constructor function
{
    std::ostringstream oss;

    function(source, oss);
}

void function(std::string* &source, std::ostringstream* &oss)
{
    //function
}
```

The constructor should do things with source and oss, and then the function should also do things with them. Is it purely a syntactical error, or am I trying to do something impossible?

Comment: You've confused reference syntax with pointer syntax. Get rid of the `*`.

Comment: `*` is a pointer. `*&` is a reference to a pointer. Drop the `*`, you have no pointers here...

Answer (score 3):

That function doesn't take references to the objects, but to pointers. It should be

```
void function(std::string &source, std::ostringstream &oss)
```

although `source` should probably be passed by value (`std::string`) or constant reference (`const std::string &`), unless the function is supposed to modify it.

Answer (score 2):

It is a pure syntactic error, what you want to do is fine:

```
Route::Route(std::string source) //constructor function
{
    std::ostringstream oss;

    function(source, oss);
}

void function(std::string& source, std::ostringstream &oss)
{
    //function
}
```

you only need to get rid of the `*` which would mean in your case (`std::string*&`) reference to pointer of string.

I guess you may have mistaken those syntaxes with the `&` operator of C that gives the address of a variable to be given to a `foo*` type that gets an address.